# Strenght of magnetic field of moving charged particles be multiplied by n?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, accelerator-physics

If two moving charged particles moving in the same direction with constant velocity and zero acceleration in a uniform magnetic field,will the Magnetic strength of the total system be equal to the sum of the individual magnetic strengths of the individual particles ?

Comment: A particle can't have a constant velocity *and* acceleration.

Comment: What do you mean by magnetic strength? The magnetic field magnitude? At what point(s) in space? Are the particles close enough to have significant interaction? What's the need for the uniform magnetic field?

Comment: Two charged particles in a uniform magnetic field will have zero acceleration if and only if their velocity is aligned to the field. The field can therefore be neglected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxwell's equations relate the magnetic field to the electrical current. The current is simply the total charge per second carried by all the charged particles in the system. In most cases these charged particles would be the electrons flowing in a wire, but it can also be charged particles moving in a vacuum, which I think is what you have in mind.

So the answer is that yes the total magnetic field is just the sum of the magnetic fields from each individual particle, because the total current is simply the sum of all the currents due to the individual particles.

More generally, electric and magnetic fields add in a linear way. So if you have two magnetic fields $\mathbf B_1$ and $\mathbf B_2$ then the total field is simply the (vector) sum $\mathbf B = \mathbf B_1 + \mathbf B_2$.